# Drawing multiple lines on one chart in flex 4.5

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, charts, flex4.5, candlestick-chart

I have a candleStickChart in flex 4.5 with a dateTimeAxis horizontal axis.
I wish to have a button that enables to draw a line on top of that chart.
I wrote a code that each time the button is click, a new CartesianDataCanvas is created. than I do a pretty standard line drawing by listening for the MOUSE_DOWN, MOUSE_MOVE, and MOUSE_UP to draw the line.
In the MOUSE_DOWN event I create the new CartesianDataCanvas, and update the annotaionArray as described in the following code: (candles is the candleStickChart's id)

```
public function startDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    canvas = new CartesianDataCanvas;
    annotationArray.addItem(canvas);
    candles.annotationElements = annotationArray.toArray();         
    x1 = this.mouseX;
    y1 = this.mouseY;   
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, updateLine);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrawing);
}
```

Everything is working fine in the first line that i'm drawing.
The problem is that when drawing the second line, the first line is disappeared. When I'm debugging the annotationArray i can see that it is indeed consist of 2 CartesianDataCanvas objects and for somereasoen it shows onlt the last one.

Does someone knows how can I fix this to show all the CartesianDataCanvas in the array at once? 
I'm fairly new to flex so I defenetly might missed some basic stuff here. feel free to comment on basics too.

Thanks in advance
Ravid

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. 
I needed to create a new class that derived from the cartesianCanvas and override its "updateDisplayList" function to redrew the line

```
override protected function updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number ):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight );       
    drawLine();
}
```